# gulp-useref build concat scripts and css but doesn't replace <--! build --> in html

Tags: gulp

I use `gulp-usref`, `gulp-if`, `gulp-uglify`, `gulp-csso` and `gulp-file-include` to build my app.
Everything works fine in build except HTML stays as it was. My gulp file is set like this:

```
gulp.task('html', ['diststyles', 'scripts'], function () {
var assets = $.useref.assets();

return gulp.src('app/*.html')
    .pipe(assets)
    .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify()))
    .pipe(gulpif('*.css', minifyCss()))
    .pipe(assets.restore())
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .pipe($.size());
});
```

diststyles and scripts are set like this:

```
gulp.task('diststyles', function () {
return gulp.src('app/styles/scss/*.scss')
    .pipe($.sass({
        errLogToConsole: true,
        includePaths: ['app/bower_components/foundation/scss'],
    }))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer('last 2 version'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/styles'))
    .pipe(reload({stream:true}))
    .pipe($.size())
    .pipe($.notify("Compilation complete."));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
return gulp.src('app/scripts/**/*.js')
    .pipe($.jshint())
    .pipe($.jshint.reporter(require('jshint-stylish')))
    .pipe($.size());
});
```

the file structure I use is this:

```
root
+-- app
    +-- bower_components
    +-- components
        header.html
        footer.html
    +-- pages
        home.html
    +-- scripts
        main.js
    +-- svg
+-- dist
    +-- scripts
        +-- vendor
            modernizr.js
        main.js
        plugins.js
        vendor.js
    +-- styles
        main.css
    home.html
```

When I run gulp first I include components into html pages (ina pages folder) and copy them to app folder. form app folder (after include is done) html tast starts. I got all my js and css files concated and copied to dist as it should be, But in html file it rests like this:

```
<!-- build:css({.tmp,app}) styles/menu.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/menu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/fonts.css">
<!-- endbuild -->`
```

Any ideas what caused the problem and how to resolve this?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Any luck figuring it out? The vendor.js script tag is not being inserted into my html files either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem but the resolution was something different. It turned out that the problem was caused by the line endings.

Originally my files used windows-style line endings. That time everything worked fine. When I changed it to unix-style line endings then it went wrong. The symptom was the same as bigcat described.

I don't think unix-style line endings are wrong in general. (Obviously they aren't.:)) There were probably some misalignment between the different files I used. I had no time to investigate it further but if you have such symptoms then it's good to know where to start.

Comment: I was having the exact same problem and was able to fix it because of this answer. Changing the line ending style from Unix to Windows fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and I used [gulp-eol](https://github.com/fritx/gulp-eol) to solve that. Example of use:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var useref = require('gulp-useref');
var eol = require('gulp-eol');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe(eol('\r\n'))
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist')); });
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked. I just updated all my npm modules to newer version and it started to work.